# Babel install does not work through npm

Tags: javascript, npm, installation, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm trying to install ES6 through Babel by following this [guy](http://www.2ality.com/2015/08/getting-started-es6.html) but I'm getting a mistake from my terminal. This is what I see after doing npm install --global babel

```
/usr/local/bin/babel -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel/cli.js
/usr/local/bin/babel-node -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel/cli.js
/usr/local/bin/babel-external-helpers -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel/cli.js
babel@6.5.2 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel
```

When I type in babel-node

```
You have mistakenly installed the `babel` package, which is a no-op in Babel 6.
Babel's CLI commands have been moved from the `babel` package to the `babel-cli` package.

    npm uninstall babel
    npm install babel-cli

See http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/ for setup instructions.
```

I get the same response as before when I try npm uninstall babel

Comment: What about the message do you not understand? Babel recently upgraded to 6 which changed a few things. You can either install the cli like the message suggests or possibly use an older version of babel. Btw, ES6 is not something you install.

Comment: what does it mean for the package to be a no-op? what is a no-op? i get the same error message when i try to npm uninstall babel, so i can't do what the prompt tells me to do

Answer (score 9):

Use this.

```
npm install --global babel-cli
```

This installs it globally and works perfectly.
And check your package.json, whether babel-cli node is created under dev dependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {"babel-cli": "^6.14.0"}
```

Answer (score 2):

some version mismatch for sure. I following the instruction of removing babel and then installing babel cli to local and global.

```
npm uninstall babel 
npm install --global babel-cli (this alone was   not enough) 
npm install babel-cli
```

It worked fine after that.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy! you need **path** babel

For example

```
sudo ./node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel.js --watch es6.js --out-file es5.js
```

Comment: what would this do exactly? this would only work if i have babel on a project and not locally, right?

Comment: yeah! but you can change path babel

Comment: how does this work if npm isn't even letting me install babel?

Answer (score 0):

To run my `Node.js` application with **ES6** features enabled, this is what I did !.

In my `package.json` file I have added 2 **devDependencies**.

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.0.0"
  }
```

And then writing `babel-node --presets es2015 app.js` in the terminal did the job well.

Here `app.js` is the main file in the project some people may call it `server.js` or `index.js.